# Is there an efficient way of finding a version with a specific tag on s3 with boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm currently trying to find specific versions of objects on s3 using boto3. For each object, there are ~5 versions, of which one has the tag I'm looking for, lets call it `SPAM`

The two functions I know that can deal with these two pieces of information are `list_object_versions` and `get_object_tagging`.

`list_object_versions` gives the versions but not the tagging, and `get_object_tagging` gives the tagset but only for a specific version. It would seem that if I wanted to find my `SPAM` tagged version, I would have to make N x V network calls:

```
list_of_keys=["a","b","c"] #<--- Size N
spam_versions={}
for key in list_of_keys:
    version_response=s3_client.list_object_versions(Bucket="My-Bucket", Key=key)

    for versionId in version_response['Versions']: #<--- Size V
        tagging_response=s3_client.get_object_tagging(Bucket="My-Bucket",Key=key,VersionId=versionId)
        tag_keys=[tag_dict['Key'] for tag_dict in tagging_response['TagSet']]
        if "SPAM" in tag_keys:
            spam_versions[key]=versionId
            break
```

Am I missing something in the API that would allow me to return tagging information with `list_object_versions` or get me every version's tagset upon calling `get_object_tagging`?

Comment: You've got the gist of it correct.  I would just consider [building a bespoke metadata index](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-and-maintaining-an-amazon-s3-metadata-index-without-servers/) so you can offload the work if you have a scenario where you'll need to make this sort of query more than once.